# Dialog Form Closes After Error

Tags: c#, winforms

Calling the Subform:

```
using (Form2 addEmp = new Form2()) 
{ 
  DialogResult dr = new DialogResult ();
  addEmp.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
  dr = addEmp.ShowDialog();
  if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    retrive = addEmp.GetEmployee;
    addtoTextFileCombo(retrive);
  }
} 

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    iD++;
    this.GetEmployee = new Employee(iD, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtEmail.Text);
  }
  catch (ArgumentNullException msg)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(msg.Message);
  }
}
```

I've created a subform to add an Employee to my main form. My problem is:
When the messagebox pops up to tell the user about the empty parameter, Form2 closes after the user clicks okay on the MessageBox informing them. How do I stop Form 2 from closing allowing the user to enter the required data?

Comment: you should do actual data validation rather than rely on exceptions.  your message isnt very helpful since it doesnt tell them *which* parameter is invalid/empty

Comment: @Plutonix - I do in fact tell them, the employee object contains a throw, with the appropriate message.

Comment: Do you have your Add button setup as the form's AcceptButton property?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. Let me try and report back

Comment: @LarsTech - I have the dialogResult set to Ok, if that is what you're asking.

Comment: Set it back to 'None'  Set it manually in your code: `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` after the `this.GetEmployee(...)` line.  Changing a form's DialogResult property from None will start the close process, so you only want to do that when you know it's ok to close.

Comment: @LarsTech - If I could give you a million points on SO, I would, but thanks for the help :D Much appropriated.

Comment: @LarsTech - I have to push the add button twice for it to close and pass the parameter. How do I fix that?

Comment: I can't see what you changed.  It's not clear to me how you would even be getting an error message to show up since those parameters look like TextBoxes, so they would never be null.  I'm assuming btnAdd is in Form2.  Put a LineBreak at the beginning of that code and watch what happens when you press the button.  Maybe change ArgumentNullException to just Exception.

Comment: @LarsTech - I fixed it. Check my updated code. See if I implemented it correctly.

Comment: @LarsTech  - Was it done correctly? It works, but did I implement the DialogResult right?

Comment: That should work.  If it takes two clicks to run, something else is going on we can't see.  Best to use a debugger break on the btnAdd_Click line and step through the code line by line to see what happens.

Comment: It does work, when I did it the first time, I did it incorrectly, I said btnAdd.Dialog instead of this.Dialog. I re-read what you posted, and tried it. It works now. You had it right from the beginning.

Comment: @LarsTech - Why did you make an edit?

Comment: I removed the line of code you added, since that turned your question into something that worked.  I posted an answer in it's place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the DialogResult value for the btnAdd control back to None, and try setting the value of the DialogResult in your code, when you know the form can be successfully closed:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    iD++;
    this.GetEmployee = new Employee(iD, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtEmail.Text);
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;   
  }
  catch (ArgumentNullException msg)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(msg.Message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check DialogResult property of AddBtn button and verify it's empty.

Comment: Could you perhaps show me? I'm completely lost at what to do.